# tableview cell extra swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an tableview with array

```
var scheduledShootsArray = ["a","b","c","e","f","c","e","f"]
```

my tableview datasources.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return isScheduledShootSelected ? scheduledShootsArray.count : completedShootsArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = segmentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ShootsTableViewCell
     if isScheduledShootSelected {
        
        cell.fimName.text = scheduledShootsArray[indexPath.row]
     } 
     return cell
   }
```

[image]

its having extra 2 empty cells how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because although they are not filled with data by default `UITableView` wil always show separators. You can solve this in a few ways

**Solution 1**:
Add clear footer to your tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView()
}
```

**Solution 2**: Add footer on setup tableview

```
func setupTableView() {
    // Set delegates etc.
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

**Solution 3**: Remove your separator lines

```
func setupTableView() {
    // Set delegates etc.
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
}
```